# Any good alternative to Google Alerts?

Tags: webapp-rec, google-alerts

[Google Alerts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Alerts) is a decent web application, and I use it for following some topics, but I receive one email pr. topic every day, and it's a bit hard to track.

Are there any good alternatives, for example one that would enable me to follow multiple topics and get notified on news in different categories?

Something that combines social media, web search, news and blogs would be of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find [Social Mention](http://www.socialmention.com) even more complete than Google Alerts.

Answer (score 0):

[Giga Alerts](http://www.gigaalert.com/about.php) is the only alternative I've found.

Your other alternative is to have Google Alerts syndicate your alerts through RSS feeds instead of email. Then you can mash all the RSS feeds up into a single RSS feed using Yahoo! Pipes.

Comment: I don't like that Giga Alerts say "Giga Alert, formerly known as Google Alert" that's just lying...

Answer (score -1):

Major Disclaimer: I'm the co-founder. But, check out [SocialBlaze](http://socialblazeapp.com); we do a lot of things but among them are email alerts for mentions of keywords/topics from all over the web.

Out of curiosity, why and how are you using this data?

Comment: Thanks, I signed up and will give this a try when I receive a beta invite.

Comment: Domain is now used by a spammer.